# Laravel Eloquent where function doesn't work(?)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If got the following database table:
[image: db-table]

Now I want to display the rows where where "inventory_warning" is greater then the "inventory" field. Like the second results as show below:

[image: screenshot]

In my first example I do a where statement using Eloquent and try to get the rows, but it doesn't yield correct results (it retrieves all rows). My second example shows the check done with a PHP-if statement, which works but will be very inefficient when the table contains more data..

Shortened code:

```
<?php $products = Product::where('inventory_warning', '>', 'inventory')->get();?>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">First results:</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td># {{ $product->id }} - {{$product->item->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->inventory }}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->inventory_warning }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

<?php $products = Product::all();?>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Second results:</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        @if($product->inventory_warning > $product->inventory)
            <tr>
                <td># {{ $product->id }} - {{$product->item->name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->inventory }}</td>
                <td>{{ $product->inventory_warning }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

**What is going on here? Is this a possible Eloquent bug or am I doing something wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing two database fields isn't supported by the `where` function as far as i know.
You'll have to use `whereRaw`

```
Product::whereRaw('inventory_warning > inventory')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! That seems to work, a quick look at the source of Eloquent confirms that the where function indeed doesn't support field comparison. (would have expected that tho..)

Function declaration:
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')